# pandas - Remove a particular character as well as the previous and subsequent characters

Tags: pandas, parsing, str-replace, bengali

I have translated Bengali phonetics into English. But after parsing, I got some trash characters, which I want to remove. My data frame looks like this.

```
col1        
utto্tor        
dokkho্shin     
muuns্si
```

So I want to remove the trash character along with its previous and following character as well. For example: In the first row, I want to remove **্**   - this character and also the character **o** and **t**, which is the adjacent of **্** (this) character.

My desired output is looks like the following-

```
col1            col2
utto্tor        uttor
dokkho্shin     dokkhhin
muuns্si        muuni
```

***P.S.*** I have got these kind of character by using *Avro parser* which looks like below:

```
reversed_text = avro.reverse("উত্তর")
print(reversed_text)

output: utto্tor
```

```
col0        col1
উত্তর       utto্tor
দক্ষিণ      dokkho্shin
মুন্সী         muuns্si
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) removing all non ascii characters and the characters before/after them:

```
df['col2'] = df['col1'].str.replace(r'.[^\x00-\x7F].', '', regex=True)
```

output:

```
         col1      col2
0     utto্tor     uttor
1  dokkho্shin  dokkhhin
2     muuns্si     muuni
```

Comment: thanks! Would you mind explaining which part of the regex removes the characters before/after? @mozway

Comment: @asif the two periods `.`

Answer (score 0):

The pandas str accessor should provide you the required functionality.
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html

Example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': ['Text1', 'Text2']})
df['Col1'] = df['Col1'].str.replace("Text", "newText")
df
```

It allows also the use of regular expressions.

Comment: my "newText' isn't always static. So I can't pre-define the characters.

Comment: @mozway 's answer does the trick for the concrete question.